# How to add reference to System.EnterpriseServices in VS 2017RC

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, .net-core, visual-studio-2017

How can I add a reference to System.EnterpriseServices in a project created with the template ASP.NET Core Web Application (.NET Framework) in VS2017RC? As you see in the screenshot, there is no option to add System.* assemblies.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

I managed to add `System.*` assemblies in a ASP.NET Core Web Application (.NET Framework) in VS2017 RC.  I am not sure if there is any other better solution.

1. After opening the project, Go to  View - > Object Browser
2. Select the .net framework which you are targetting your ASP.NET Core Web Application
3. Search for  `System.EnterpriseServices`
4. You will get one result, On the right side you will get details about the assembly. Click the Hyperlink `System.EnterpriseServices`
5. You will be shown the physical path of the assembly
6. Copy that path, Go to `Add Reference` window and browse that path.
7. It adds `System.EnterpriseServices` dll to your project.

[image]

It adds the local machine path to .csproj file while adding reference. Need to be careful while deployments.